# How to send localStorage from JS to PHP file (?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, local-storage

I am trying to move localStorage content to a php email file. The localStorage was created with Javascript. The thankyou.php **CAN** use JS/jQuery BUT the email file (admin-new-order.php **CANNOT** use JS or jQuery...

Here is the code I am using. It's not working properly:

JS on **thankyou.php** (**1**st page):

```
  <script>
      var value = localStorage.totallocal;

      jQuery.post(
            "admin-new-order.php", 
            {myKey: value}, 
            function(data){
               var value = localStorage.totallocal;
            }).fail(function()
               {
                   alert("error");
            });
       }
  </script>
```

PHP on **admin-new-order.php** (**2**nd page/sent to email inbox). Retrieves value from **thankyou.php**:

```
    <p><?php  $value = $_POST["value"]; printf("%u",$value); ?></p>
```

The email file shows this: 0 but the value from localStorage should always be between 0.01 - 10000.00. I don't think it is receiving the localStorage...but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am new to php.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Santosh

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: No errors. In Chrome console it shows the localStorage. Unfortunately it is not carrying to admin-new-order.php (maybe because it's received in email inbox)? Thanks again @SantoshRamKunjir

Comment: POST vars are strings, not numbers, does that matter with `printf`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$_POST["value"]` it should be `$_POST["myKey"]`

```
<p><?php  $value = $_POST["myKey"]; printf("%u",$value); ?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you @JagsSparrow. Unfortunately it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot access localstorage via PHP.** You need to write some javascript that sends the localstorage data back to the script.

If you are using jQuery, do something like the following.

**set_page.php**

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem('email', '<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>');  
localStorage.setItem('password', '<?php echo $_SESSION['password'];?>');
</script>
```

**login_page.php**

```
<script>
var email = localStorage.getItem('email'), password = localStorage.getItem('password');
$.POST('login_response.php', {'email':email,'password':password}, function(data){
  alert('Login Successful.  Redirect to a different page or something here.');
}
</script>
```

**login_response.php**

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//Handle your login here.  Set session data, etc.  Be sure to sanitize your inputs.
?>
```